# Oracle to Hibernate to ISO 8601 Date format

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, datetime

I have an Entity field declared as Date and is mapped to a date field in oracle.
When I print the value for that field, I get the date format like  `2013-04-23 09:05:03.0`.

I need to convert this date to ISO 8601 format. So I used:

```
System.out.println("Converted Date:" + asXMLGregorianCalendar(retrunedDate);

private static DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();

public static XMLGregorianCalendar asXMLGregorianCalendar(java.util.Date date) {
    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        return df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    }
}
```

The following code returns:

```
System.out.println("Converted Date:" + asXMLGregorianCalendar(retrunedDate);

// Output
Converted Date: 2013-04-23T09:05:03.000-05:00
```

Questions:

1. There is `000` instead of the actual number. Not sure why?
2. What is the `0` at the end from hibernate `2013-04-23 09:05:03.0`? How do I get the full date?

When I pass the `Date`, I get the result I need.:

```
System.out.println("Converted Date:" + asXMLGregorianCalendar(new Date());

// Output
Converted Date: 2013-08-23T17:19:15.664-05:00
```

This is what I need. Instead of `000`, I need to get milliseconds.
Is Hibernate doing something with the date?

Comment: 0 is the milli second. What do you mean by 'full date'? The date printed out looks pretty full to me. Then again ISO 8601 format is too vague. ISO 8601 describes a large number of date/time formats. Can you tell me what is the format of the date you are trying to achieve? Then, I can help you on how to achieve it.

Comment: The problem would appear to be that whatever is putting data *into* your database is truncating to the nearest second.  The code for printing it back out is fine.

Comment: When I check the Database, I see standard ORACLE date format yy-MMM-dd. I don't see any issue with this.

Comment: Or, Is there a way I can see full date stored in the database?

Comment: 000 is the millisecond. I don't see a problem here. 1000 milliseconds make a second. So milliseconds can have any value between 000 and 999. Make sure your database is storing milliseconds as well. Otherwise you will always see 000.

Comment: You can see the full value as stored in oracle with a query like: `select to_char(timestampColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3') from table;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle `DATE` datatype does not store fractional seconds.  If you want to store and recover milliseconds you need to change the data type of the column to `TIMESTAMP`.